# How can I add a folder location in database?

Tags: c#

I am developing an Multimedia Data management System, where I need to save any folder location path in database using textbox. I retrieve data by Data Grid View and from the Data Grid View I want to click the path and folder should be opened. So how can I do this?

I give my project view picture:

[image]

```
private void Save_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string movieName = Name_textBox1.Text;
        string folderLocation = location_textBox2.Text;

        string query = "INSERT INTO movie(Name ,Location ) VALUES('" + movieName + "','" + folderLocation + "')";
        op.SaveInformation(query);
        op.Load_Table1(dataGridView1);        
        Name_textBox1.Text= "";
        location_textBox2.Text= "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void Load_Table1(DataGridView dv)
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM movie;";
    SqlConnection Conn = op.create_connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dataset = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dataset);
        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = dataset;
        dv.DataSource = bSource;
        sda.Update(dataset);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public void SaveInformation(string query)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection Conn = create_connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Conn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Conn.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("InformationSaved Successfully", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use openfiledialog?

Comment: [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog)

Comment: What exactly do you want help with? To create a clickable cell? To open the folder in Explorer? Also, your questions title does not match your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is vulnerable to sql injection, use sql parameters to pass values to sql query,

```
private void Save_button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string movieName = Name_textBox1.Text;
                string folderLocation = location_textBox2.Text;

                String query = "INSERT INTO movie(Name ,Location ) VALUES(@movieName,@folderLocation)";
                op.Parameters.AddWithValue("@movieName",movieName);
                op.Parameters.AddWithValue("@folderLocation",folderLocation);
                op.SaveInformation(query);
                op.Load_Table1(dataGridView1);


                Name_textBox1.Text= "";
               location_textBox2.Text= "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

In this way you can store any string with slash or quotes

Comment: This does not answer the OPs question.

Comment: +1 for pointing out (**yet again!**) the SQL injection vulnerability and how to fix it

Comment: i want to save a folder location link say open a folder copy the folder location and save it to the database. when i retrieve the folder location link from the database i click the link and folder is opened.

Comment: use Process.Start(link); to open that folder, link should be your clicked cell value. It must be folder location

Comment: You can use openFolderDialog to open and select folder

Answer (score 0):

This will open the C:\ directory.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\");`

Just specify any string (watch out because this will run anything, including files like Word documents or EXEs).

```
var varX = "C:\\myfolder\\hello";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(varX);
```

Also note in your database you have invalid URL: C\x is not valid. There should be a colon (:) after the drive letter.

To take this action and open the folder once the cell is clicked, simply subscribe/handle the Cell Clicked event: here's the docs ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Let me know if you need help doing that.

Comment: u can see my project picture then tell me how can i save any folder location using textbox or something. I don't find any resources to do this.

Comment: i want to save a folder location link say open a folder copy the folder location and save it to the database. when i retrieve the folder location link from the database i click the link and folder is opened. –

Comment: your code open me a folder but i want to open it from data grid view and how?????